# loggingのaddHandlerの多重実行を防止する方法

Tags: python, python3

JupyterLabやGoogleColabで、以下のコードを複数回実行すると、ログも重複して出力されるようになります。
addHandlerが何度も呼び出されるのが原因と思われます。
Kernel(Pythonプロセス)をリセットせずに、セルを何度実行しても、
ログが重複出力されないよう防止する方法はないでしょうか？
（独自に設定したloggerかそうでないか判定することができると助かります。）

```
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, Formatter, shutdown
from logging import DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL

def init_logger(name='test.sample'):
    # Streamハンドラー
    stream_formatter = Formatter(
        fmt='[%(asctime)s] <%(levelname)s> - %(message)s',
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z" # なぜか%zは機能しない
    )
    stream_handler = StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(DEBUG)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(stream_formatter)

    logger = getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    logger.propagate = False
init_logger()

# ログ出力部
logger = getLogger('test.sample')
logger.debug(777)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logger.addHandler` に設定したハンドラは `logger.handlers` 変数に格納されます。
handlersへは、「同じハンドラは2重登録しない」ようになっていますが、別のハンドラインスタンスを作成してaddHandlerに渡した場合、「違うハンドラ」なので登録されてしまいます。

コード
[`https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1448`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1448)
[`https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1640-L1649`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1640-L1649)

環境全体のロギング設定を一定に保つことが目的であれば、[logging.basicConfig(...)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)や[logging.dictConfig(...）](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig)を使って、起動時に一度だけ初期化するように実装するべきです。

そうできない事情がある場合、今回のケースで一番簡単な対処方法は、logger.handlersをリセットしてしまうことです。

```py
    logger = getLogger(name)
    for h in logger.handlers[:]:
        logger.removeHandler(h)
        h.close()
    logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    logger.propagate = False
```

参考コード: [`https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2022-L2025`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.1/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2022-L2025)

> （独自に設定したloggerかそうでないか判定することができると助かります。）

rootロガー以外は後から追加されるロガーのため、自分のコードで追加したものか、ライブラリで追加したものかの見分けが付きません。
例えば、getLoggerしたあとに独自の属性をセットする方法で初期化済みか判定する方法が考えられます。

```py
    logger = getLogger(name)
    if not getattr(logger, 'my_init', False):
        logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        logger.propagate = False
        logger.my_init = True
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
1.handlerを都度リセットする方法
2.loggerオブジェクトに初期化した印をつける方法
理解できました。
2の方法で進めていこうと思います。
ライブラリ側で提供しているクラスのインスタンスに、独自のプロパティを設定することがリスク（作法違反）になりますが、許容できるかなと（仕方ないと）思いました。ありがとうございました。